# How precise the space in which an inner product is done?

Tags: math-mode, formatting

I am using the `\langle` and `\langle` function and I want to precise (in index) the space in which this inner product is defined. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Perhaps `\rangle_{V}`?

Comment: @egreg Indeed, it was just that... Thanks !

Answer (score 2):

`Mathtools` lets  you have an automatic sizing of the delimiters:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools, nccmath}
\usepackage{xparse, etoolbox}

\DeclarePairedDelimiterX{\innerp}[1]{\langle}{\rangle}{\innpargs{#1}}
\NewDocumentCommand{\innpargs}{>{\SplitArgument{1}{,}}m}
{\innpargsaux#1}
\NewDocumentCommand{\innpargsaux}{mm}
{\ifblank{#1}%
{\ifblank{#2}{~{,}~}{{\,\cdot\,}{,}{\mkern2mu#2}}}%
{{#1\,}{,}\ifblank{#2}{\,\cdot\,}{\mkern2mu#2}}%
}%

%}%
\begin{document}

\[ \innerp{u, v}_{\!_E}, \quad \innerp*{\tfrac{1}{2}u, v}_{\!E} \quad \innerp*{\frac{u}{2}, v}_{\!E} \]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I am using your solution in a paper, but I find the space after the comma is too small for some characters (e.g.,\innerp{V, R} ). How can I fix this? Just adding some extra space for all styles would be good enough, I think.

Comment: You can slightly increase the value of \ \mkern` (1mu=1/18em, and, for instance `\,`=3mu, `\:`=4mu, `\;`=5mu. But maybe this is an optical impreesien, due to the basis of `V` too far from the comma, so try also with `V\mkern -1mu`(or another negative value).

Comment: Thank you! After a bit of trial-and-error I found a solution I am satisfied with using \mkern. I also added \mkern2mu between the brackets and the variables, since my variables tend to be more complicated than your example and it all looks a bit cramped.